# Mutate to Create Minimum in Each Row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question relating to creating a minimum value in a new column in dplyr using the mutate function based off two other columns.

The following code repeats the same value for each row in the new column.  Is there a way to create an independent minimum for each row in the new column?  I wish to avoid using loops or the apply family due to speed and would like to stick with dplyr if possible.  Here's the code:

```
a = data.frame(runif(5,0,5))
b = data.frame(runif(5,0,5))
c = data.frame(runif(5,0,5))

y = cbind(a,b,c)

colnames(y) = c("a","b","c")

y = mutate(y, d = min(y$b, y$c))

y
```

The new column "d" is simply a repeat of the same number.  Any suggestions on how to fix it so that it's the minimum of "b" and "c" in each row?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A simpler way to create `y` is to do `y = data.frame(a, b, c)` then you don't need to separately set `colnames`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `pmin`

```
y$d <- with(y, pmin(b, c))
```

Or

```
transform(y, d = pmin(b,c))
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
y %>%
  mutate(d = pmin(b,c))
```

`min` works columnwise, suppose if we want to use `min`, an option would be

```
y %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(d = min(unlist(c(b,c))))
```

Comment: That (pmin) worked.   Thank you.   Will accept the answer once I can (after 7 minutes).   Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `min` function apply by rows rather than columns by using the `apply` function and setting the `margin` argument to `MARGIN = 1`. Your rowwise min function would look like this:

```
apply(y, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) min(x)))
```

Then, in order to make the rowwise min function only apply to columns b and c, you could use the `select` function within `mutate`, like this:

```
y %>% mutate(b.c.min = 
  y %>%
    select(one_of("b", "c")) %>%
    apply(MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) min(x)))
```